# REST API results return after index.html page loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest

I am fetching data from a REST API in AngularJS. The REST API returns the results after sometime by the time, the index.html is already loaded. It no longer displays the REST API results.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The content is {{greeting}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://example.com/api/v1/search/searchByDesc?searchType=space_name&searchValue=MLX800').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.greeting = response.data;
        });
});
```

In the debugger, I can see the REST API returning results.

How do I display the results on the browser?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

your api endpoint isn't working.

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(function(response) {
            $scope.greeting = response.data;
            console.log(response.data)
        });
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The content is {{greeting}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The REST API is returning a JSON object after 31 secs. The strange thing is it's not displayed on the console. But I could see the 200 HTTP response and the result in the debugger.

Comment: Can you share what api endpoint are u using? this one https://example.com/api/v1/search/searchByDesc?searchType=space_name&searchValue=MLX800' isn't* returning any json object